# Impedir a ação de recarregar a página ao clicar no OK do ALERT JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu faço uma verificação bem tosca pra ver se o formulário está preenchido, caso ele não esteja aparece um `alert("Preencha todos os campos!");`, o problema é que quando eu clico no OK ele recarrega a página e assim limpando o formulário.

- Preciso que o botão do OK do alert não limpe o formulário.
- Se possível quero que marque em vermelho os campos que não estiverem preenchidos.

JS

```
$('#btnCadMed').click(function(){
        var nome = $("#txtNome").val();
        var CRM = $("#txtCRM").val();
        var idt = $("#txtIdentificador").val();
        var esp = $("#txtEspecialidade").val();
        if(nome == "" || CRM == "" || idt == "" || esp == ""){
            alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
        }else{
            $("#txtNome").val("");
            $("#txtCRM").val("");
            $("#txtIdentificador").val("");
            $("#txtEspecialidade").val("");
            alert("Médico cadastrado com sucesso!");
        }
    });
```

Print do alert
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar um return false ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu botão está postando o formulário, devido a isso que está sendo recarregado a página.

Faz o seguinte, muda para:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        var nome = $("#txtNome").val();
        var CRM = $("#txtCRM").val();
        var idt = $("#txtIdentificador").val();
        var esp = $("#txtEspecialidade").val();
        if(nome == "" || CRM == "" || idt == "" || esp == ""){
            alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
            return false;
        }else{
            $("#txtNome").val("");
            $("#txtCRM").val("");
            $("#txtIdentificador").val("");
            $("#txtEspecialidade").val("");
            alert("Médico cadastrado com sucesso!");
           return true
        }
    });
```

Assim, ele vai somente postar o formulário caso a condição seja verdadeira.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @IvanTeles está correta e na minha opinião é que deve ser usada, mas apenas para efeito de informação:

```
$('#btnCadMed').click(function(e) {
    if(nome == "" || CRM == "" || idt == "" || esp == ""){
        alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
        e.preventDefault();
```

`e.preventDefault()` deve funcionar tão bem como o `return false` funciona no evento `submit` do formulário.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gcc006y/)**</kbd>

Comment: Na minha opinião é esta a resposta certa. `e.preventDefault();` é semanticamente mais correto.

Comment: @Sergio, sim concordo. Eu quis dizer que usar o evento no form seria mais correto do que no botão em si. Talvez mesclando as duas respostas ele teria a ideal.